# If&Else stuck on return

Tags: php, math, if-statement

(sorry for my bad English writing). I've got a problem where I'm stuck with an if and else system that returns the level that you're.

Everything is good, if you have 20 clicks it will tell you that you're level 2, if you have 550 clicks it will tell you're level 6. But when you go up to 1500 clicks it needs to say level 9, but it will still say level 8.

My code:

```
$levelown = 'Level 1';

function ifElse() {

    global $levelown;
    global $arrayIP;

    if($arrayIP['clicks'] >= 0 && $arrayIP['clicks'] <= 49)
        {
            $levelown = 'Level 2';
        }
    /* .... More if and elses with levels */

    // This is the problem, this will keep telling me that I'm level 8.
    elseif($arrayIP['clicks']>=3000)
        {
            $levelown = 'Level ' . floor(($score['clicks']/1000)+8);
        }



and you are <strong><?php echo $levelown; ?></strong>
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: You can simplify it: get rid of all the `>=` tests. Since the previous test was false, you know that the number is higher than its range.

Comment: Thank you, I now know that that floor() part keeps telling me that I'm level 8. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/rJOnZndc

Comment: Did you copy and paste directly from your actual source code? If not, there's probably a typo in the real code.

Comment: `$score['clicks']` should be `$arrayIP['clicks']`?

Comment: Why did you edit out all the details? If there's a problem with a specific case, how can we see it now?

Comment: Yeah, put the details back in please - there may be a better solution we can help you with.

Comment: I've edited because it was the same as every if, I'm sorry for deleting it. But its fixed now thanks to happyjack. It was a typo, $scoreclicks needs to be $arrayIP. I'm sorry for this dumb mistake :-(

Comment: You are getting zero because you have `$score['clicks'] == 0` so according to your input, it will always send you level 8

Comment: But it shouldn't get to that code unless `$arrayIP['clicks']` is at least 3000. The question says he's having a problem when it's 1500.

Comment: @Barmar:his questions does say that but his code isnt saying that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that i saw from your current code is that you have

```
 elseif($arrayIP['clicks']>=3000)
        {
            $levelown = 'Level ' . floor(($score['clicks']/1000)+8);
        }
```

which i think should be

```
 elseif($arrayIP['clicks']>=3000)
        {
            $levelown = 'Level ' . floor(($arrayIP['clicks']/1000)+8);
        }
```

since `$score['clicks']` isn't present you will always end up with level 8

Comment: The question says he gets the wrong level when clicks is 1500. This incorrect code only runs when clicks is >= 3000.

Comment: @Barmar: My friend his question does say that but, his code is not saying that

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easier and more readable to make it a switch/case statement like so:

```
$highscore   = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name,clicks,ip,factory FROM highscore ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 0,50 ");
$ipquery     = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,name,clicks,ip,factory FROM highscore WHERE ip = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'");
$arrayIP     = $ipquery->fetch_array();

$levelown = 1;

function ifElse() {
global $levelown;
global $arrayIP;

    switch (true) {
        case $arrayIP['click'] > 3000:
            $levelown = floor(($arrayIP['click']/1000)+8);
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click']== 3000:
            $levelown = 11;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 2000:
            $levelown = 10;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 1500:
            $levelown = 9;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 1000:
            $levelown = 8;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 750:
            $levelown = 7;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 500:
            $levelown = 6;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 350:
            $levelown = 5;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 200:
            $levelown = 4;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 50:
            $levelown = 3;
            break;
        case $arrayIP['click'] >= 0:
            $levelown = 2;
            break;
    }
    $levelown = "Level " . $levelown;
}
```